# solr search result issue (searching for shirt returning t-shirt)

Tags: solr

I'm using solr 6.3.0 to search product from the document, my problem is when i search for "mens shirt" then it also searches the "mens t-shirt" in the result. But i don't want the result "mens t-shirt" for that what shluld id do?

```
Fields details as given below.


<field name="product_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>      
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>      
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>


Thanks
abhay
```

Comment: Hello,

As i got to know about the 'Classic Tokenizer' 

Words are split at hyphens, unless there is a number in the word, in which case the token is not split and the numbers and hyphen(s) are preserved.

So i think 't-shirt' will be split in "t" and "shirt" and my problem is yest not resolved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the StandardTokenizer is splitting at - too, that is why it matches 'shirt'. For this case specifical case, you could just replace StandardTokenizerFactory with ClassicTokenizerFactory.

ClassicTokenizerFactory does not split on -, so t-shit will not match shirt. That said, maybe there are other cases where you will miss StandardTokenizerFactory.

Look at the [docs for tokenizers](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html), experiment a bit, and then decide

Comment: Hello, As i got to know about the 'Classic Tokenizer' Words are split at hyphens, unless there is a number in the word, in which case the token is not split and the numbers and hyphen(s) are preserved. So i think 't-shirt' will be split in "t" and "shirt" and my problem is yest not resolved